# Python: avoid next() error at EOF?

Tags: python

I have a program that will read a file and skip blank lines by using the next() function.

However, since the last line of the file is a blank, this produces an exception error.

Does anyone know a way around this?

current code:

```
import csv
with open(fname,'rb') as inf:
   reader = csv.reader(inf)
   for row in reader:
      while row == []:
         row = next(reader)
      do stuff
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./program.py", line 37, in <module>
    row = next(reader)
StopIteration
```

Comment: Please post your code and the exact exception.

Comment: You mean `next()` throws `StopIteration`? Why not either handle it or have `next()` return a default in that case?

Comment: But please show us a workable example of your problem; as it stands this is too vague to answer concretely.

Comment: @MartijnPieters can you please explain?

Comment: @andrejr "But please show us a workable example of your problem" = **Please show us your code**

Comment: @MartijnPieters I was replying to his comment about saying "handle it" or "return a default" - I have no idea what either of these mean

Comment: @andrejr: you could have caught the `StopIteration` exception with an exception handler. `next()` takes a second argument, a default to return if it would otherwise have propagated the `StopIteration` exception. But the answers below show that you have better options still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the `filter` built in function on the file object.  If the file is long, `itertools.ifilter` will do this lazily.  For example `filter(None, FILE_OBJECT)` will return an iterable which iterates lines of the file, omitting blank lines (blank lines are falsey in Python).

EDIT

After seeing your actual code, use the `continue` statement instead of calling `next`

change:

```
while row == []:
    ....
```

to:

```
if row == []:
    continue
```

Comment: As it turns out, this is actually my fault; I've updated my original answer to use `continue` too.